# Perform a task on receiving a push notification in background

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, push-notification

I want to perform a task on receiving a push notification. I wrote my code in `- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary*)userInfo` method. It is working fine when application is in foreground, but when application is in background the above method is not getting called. Is there any way to make this method called when application is in background. This app is not for submitting to itunes, so any **good hack** trick ? ;)

Comment: Kindly update me if this worked or not.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever an application goes in background, all notifications start happening in backgound thread. So you need to do something like this.

```
...
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self       
                                         selector:@selector(processNotificationInBackground:) 
                                             name:TheNameOfTheNotification 
                                           object:nil];
...

- (void) processNotificationInBackground:(NSNotification *)not {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        /* your background notification processing code goes here */
        /* note that you should transfer control back to the main queue if you need to update your UI */
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you traced whether notification is generated and observed and selector is called?

Comment: yes, here selector is not getting called, i tested it by  "[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName: TheNameOfTheNotification object:self];"

Comment: So you got the issue.. just try something with your code, as your notification is either not generated or it is not observed. If both of them work fine the selector will be called and your work will be done.